# Load Adafruit GFX bitmap fonts on desktop for pixel-level design

Tags: adafruit

I am designing UI for 160x128 ST7735-based TFT display which will be displayed using Adafruit's GFX library (and the driver in `Adafruit_ST7735.h`). I am using the default bitmap font (custom fonts don't provide the white-out functionality, causing flicker) and would like to load it in some desktop pixel editor (like Gimp or some pixel-art editor) so that I can work the design out on desktop.

There are many posts about converting regular (TFT, OTF) fonts to the c-style array, I need to do the opposite. If possible, including the scaled variants, so that I have 1:1 corespondence :)

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/creating-custom-symbol-font-for-adafruit-gfx-library/understanding-the-font-specification) and [here](https://glenviewsoftware.com/projects/products/adafonteditor/adafruit-gfx-font-format/) the font format in the GFX-library is GFXglyph, you can use the [free tool from the second link adafonteditor v1.0.3](https://glenviewsoftware.files.wordpress.com/2018/10/adafonteditor_v1_0_3.zip) on the desktop.
**EDIT**
Ok so its actually decompile the gfx header file to something on the desktop. Take a look at the [Adafruit GFX Font Customiser](https://tchapi.github.io/Adafruit-GFX-Font-Customiser/) Source can be used as basis for own projects or compiled to the designated OS.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the opposite direction. I don't have a problem parsing the GFXGlyph format, but would like to convert it to standard (BDF, PCF) raster font formats desktop programs can use, without writing the converter myself. Adafonteditor is mac-only. I think I will just use standard 5x7 font shipped with x11.

Comment: Thanks, the font customiser might be a useful reference.